# How to Overlay the GeoTIFF file on Google Earh

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, google-earth, overlay, jpg

I found how to open the GeoTIFF files on the Google Earth Pro from [this site](https://www.marine.usf.edu/scamp/documents/How-to-import-Geo-TIFFs-into-Google-Earth-as-Super-Overlays.pdf).

However, though I followed the way, it just show white images on the Google Earth Pro like this:
[image]

You can see three boxes and a colorful image on the mage that I uploaded. The large white box is the Landsat8 raster image(GeoTIFF) and two small white boxes are Korean Satellite raster image(GeoTIFF). But, the rich image is the jpeg file that is overlaid successfully.

Why I cannot overlay the GeoTIFF files on the Google Earth Pro?

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is that your GeoTiff images are 3-band RGB images, which is the only type of GeoTiff that Google Earth can import & display.  Often GeoTiffs of GIS data or raw satellite imagery will have additional bands (eg: an IR band), will just have one band with a data value (eg: elevation), or will have bands that use unusual pixel values.  All of those will not work correctly when importing to Google Earth Pro.  To fix this, bring the images into your GIS software and export them as basic 3-band RGB (red/green/blue) images.  In some software this is called a "rendered image" export.